# Error with mongoDB java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using mongodb java driver 3.0.2 (I tried 3.0.1 and 3.0.0 but I get the same error).

This is the error that I get: The type org.bson.Document cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

It happens on the second line of the following code:

```
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
db.getCollection("");
```

As I understand the second line uses code that exists in org.bson.Document and it cant find it. But where can I find it?

************** EDIT ************
I know added the bson jar and it has the org.bson package BUT there is not org.bson.Document class inside this package...

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Mongo Java Driver which contains several libraries, and no the MongoDB Driver for Java? see my answer below.

Answer (score 17):

I believe you have downloaded the MongoDB-Driver for Java, and not the Mongo-Java-Driver.

Easiest way is to **download the mongo-java-driver-3.x.x.jar** library, available at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

It contains the following packages:

- MongoDB Driver
- MongoDB Async Driver
- **BSON Library**
- Core Driver

**If you install the MongoDB driver only , then you need to download BSON Library separately.**

Comment: The mongoDB installation guide for the Java driver says "There are two Maven artifacts available in the 3.4 release. The preferred artifact for new applications is mongodb-driver however, we still publish the legacy mongo-java-driver uber-jar."

Comment: i am using mongo-java-driver 3.7.1, still i am unable to import the libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Document class exist since from 3.0.0 and not in MongDB jar, it's in BSON jar file. You can download from  https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.0.2/bson-3.0.2.jar

Reference:

public class Document
extends Object
implements Map, Serializable, Bson
A representation of a document as a Map. All iterators will traverse the elements in insertion order, as with LinkedHashMap.
Since:
3.0.0

http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/org/bson/Document.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse and maven change the dependency in pom.xml as follows:-

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download the bson library (v3.0.2) and add it to your classpath :
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.0.2/bson-3.0.2.jar

Comment: Please take care: in the meanwhile 3.0.2 is not the latest version, please check out the actual version at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/

Answer (score 0):

You should check if this package is in the classpath: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/package-summary.html

Comment: Well, that's really strange... Are you sure that it is included in the classpath?

Comment: Yes it is it. The class Document is simply not there... I have no idea why